# I am a beginner in python and trying to solve this problem input=777 output=7+7+7=21>>2+1=3#till single digit; it went into infinite loop

Tags: python, string, loops, while-loop, integer

```
def  sum_of_digits(n):
    a = str(n)
    c = 0

    while len(a)>1:
        for i in range(len(a)):
            c+=int(a[i])
        a = str(c)
        #return c
        print(c)            

sum_of_digits(777)
```

Comment: You never reset ``c`` to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset the counter variable `c` before or after each iteration. In the first iteration, 777 becomes `7+7+7 = 21` and you store it in `c`. Then you convert `c` ( which is `21` ) to a string and store into `a`.

At this stage:
`c = 21 and a = "21" (String)`

After that, you have to set `c = 0` because, in the next iteration, we will again calculate the sum of `21` which will be `2+1=3` using `c += int(a[i])`. If you do not reset `c`, the previous value of `c` will be added to `3` and the value be `21 + 3 = 24` (21 from our first iteration if we don't set c = 0 ) and therefore it will keep increasing forever and create an infinite loop.

```
def  sum_of_digits(n):
    a = str(n)
    c = 0

    while len(a)>1:
        c = 0
        
        for i in range(len(a)):
            c+=int(a[i])
        a = str(c)
        #return c
        print(c)    
        
    return c
    
    
sum_of_digits(777)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
def  sum_of_digits(n):
  if(len(n) == 1):
    return n
  return int(n[0])+int(sum_of_digits(n[1:len(n)]))
    

sum = "00"
param = "0123654789"
while (len(str(sum)) != 1):
  
  sum = sum_of_digits(param)
  param = str(sum)
  
  
  
print(sum)
```

Answer (score -1):

Your program is very close to what you need, as MisterMiyagi said, reset c to 0 right after the for loop. It goes into infinite loop because your "c" was just adding number and "a" retrieving that number that always grew...
C=0 right after for loop will do the trick